# jQuery UI Slider Absolute Position

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a question about jQuery UI's slider position.

I am trying to set an absolute position for the slider. So what I have is this:

```
<div id='scrollbar_x_wrapper' >
    <div id='scrollbar_x'></div>
</div>
```

and

```
$('#scrollbar_x_wrapper').css({
    "position": 'absolute',
    "left": 100 + "px",
    "top": 100 + "px",
    'width': (chart_width * 0.85 - 15) + 'px'
})

scroll_x = $('#scrollbar_x').slider({
    value: 0
    min: 0,
    max: 5
    step: 1,

    slide: function(event, ui) {
        redraw();
    }
});
```

However, it seems if I click the track of the slider, the slider does not respond, but it only responds if I click the thumb.

When I remove the left and top style attribute, it works perfectly fine. I need to use left and top attribute to correctly position the slider in my case, so I have to use left and top attributes.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the animate property?

```
$(".SliderDiv").slider(
    { min: 0, 
      max: 16, 
      step: .25, 
      slide: SliderSlide, 
      animate: true 
    });
```

Comment: Not exactly. When I set left and top style attribute, the slider bar does not move when I click the track. It works only if I click the thumb though.

Comment: I took out your slide : redraw function (I had to since I don't have it) and it worked.

Comment: BTW, you are missing commas between your options (value, max)